# how to do a vector<class objects*> deep copy

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, deep-copy, c++98

I am having trouble with writing the Rule of three when it comes to vector of pointers to class objects. Searched and examples don't seem to apply. I have these three classes:

```
class Data
{
    private:
        map<string, double> m_DataVariables;

    public:
        Data();
        Data(const Data &data);
 };

class Sample
{
    private:
        Data *m_pData;

    public:
        virtual ~Sample()
        {
            delete m_pData;
        }

    Sample();
    Sample(const Sample &sample);
};

class BuildTree
{
    private:
        vector<Sample*> BuildSamples;

    public:
        BuildTree(vector<Sample*> &Samples);

        // This does not compile
        BuildTree(const BuildTree& other) : BuildSamples(new(other.BuildSamples))
        {
        } 

        ~TreeBuilding()                                         
        {   
            for (int i = 0; i < BuildSamples.size(); ++i)
                delete BuildSamples[i];
        }

        void BuildTrees(void);
};
```

1- Not sure if I am correctly deleting BuildSamples.

2- In the constructor want to do a deep copy of the passed parameter into member variable BuildSamples.

```
BuildTree::BuildTree(vector<Sample*> &samples)
{
    BuildSamples = samples;  // This just copies the references
}
```

How do I write the copy constructor to make a deep copy? What am I missing here?

3- Please note: don't have access to smart pointers, share_ptr or unique_ptr, etc. C++98 is what I have.
Please show the steps required to do this. Really appreciate your time and consideration.

Comment: Why not use unique_ptr?  Then the deletes take care of themselves.

Comment: @Robinson: Third point -> C++98.

Comment: Ah.  That's a shame.

Comment: why not `vector<Sample>`?

Comment: @Caleth:  Good point. The algorithm was originally done in MathLab using a pointer, but don't see why it couldn't be `vector<Smaple>`

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like:

```
BuildTree(const BuildTree& other)
{
    BuildSamples.reserve(other.BuildSamples.size());
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != other.BuildSamples.size(); ++i) {
        BuildSamples.push_back(new Sample(*other.BuildSamples[i]));
    }
}

BuildTree(const vector<Sample*> &samples)
{
    BuildSamples.reserve(samples.size());
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != samples.size(); ++i) {
        BuildSamples.push_back(new Sample(*samples[i]));
    }
}
```

Comment: you meant `new Sample(*other.BuildSamples[i])`

Comment: @WindyFields: sure, fixed.

Comment: If you change the `reserve` to a `resize` and the `push_back` to a straight assignement to i-th element the code gets both more symmetric and faster.

Comment: @Jarod42, @WindyFields: Provided suggestion code compiled correctly. I am still unclear though on how calling this other constructor               `BuildTree::BuildTree(vector<Sample*> &samples)
{
    BuildSamples = samples;  // This just copies the references
}` is handled? I suppose I still need to do something similar here to do a deep copy?

Comment: @Galan: yes you have to do the equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

I noted you marked your question as [c++98](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b98); even if C++98 doesn't support smart pointers in `std::`, you can certainly use the smart pointers defined in Boost, e.g. `boost::shared_ptr`. 
For example, instead of using raw *owning* pointers like in `vector<Sample*>`, you can make your code simpler with 
`vector<boost::shared_ptr<Sample>>`.

In this way, the copy and destruction operations will be *automatically* implemented under the hood.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to use Boost. Had looked into it, but this code is intended for an embedded application and unable to link in Boost support.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialise the `BuildSamples` member as a vector of pointers, and ensure every pointer points at a clone of the objects passed.  One way is

```
BuildTree(const BuildTree& other) : BuildSamples(other.BuildSamples)
{
     std::vector<Sample *>::iterator i = BuildSamples.begin(), end = BuildSamples.end();
     while (i != end)
     {
         *i = new Sample(**i);
         ++i;
     }
}
```

The usage of `BuildSamples(other.BuildSamples)` initialises `BuildSamples` with the correct number of elements, but those elements are the same pointers as in `other.BuildSamples`.   This ensures the vector is of the correct size, without worrying about setting the size explicitly.   That is a shallow copy.    The body of the constructor then sets every element of `BuildSamples` so it points at a clone of itself - thus completes the deep copy.

The constructor `BuildTree(const std::vector<Sample *> &)` can be implemented in a similar manner.

Note:  given that your class is implementing a non-trivial copy constructor (to do the deep copy) and a destructor to cleanup, you also need to implement an assignment operator `BuildTree &operator=(const BuildTree &)`.   For an explanation why, look up the "rule of three".

Answer (score 0):

While dealing with pointers and to avoid crashing of a running program due to destructor being called, Deep copy must be used! deep copy allows creating a new pointer pointing to a newly allocated space. But when passing objects as R-value in vector it is better to use the move constructor.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>
    using namespace std;
    class example{
        private:
         int *pointer;
    public:
        //constructor
        example(int d){
            pointer = new int;
            *pointer = d;
            cout<<"Constructor Called"<<endl;
        }


    // deep copy
        example(const example &source){
            pointer = new int;
            *pointer= *source.pointer;
            cout<<"deep copy made"<<endl;
        }
    // Move Constructor
        example(example &&source) noexcept :pointer{source.pointer}{
        source.pointer = nullptr;
        cout << "object moved"<<endl;
        }
// Destructor
        ~example() {
            delete pointer;
            cout << "Destroyed"<<endl;
        }

    };

    int main()
    {

        vector <example> vec;
        vec.push_back(example{300});
        vec.push_back(example{300});
        vec.push_back(example{300});
        vec.push_back(example{300});
        return 0;
    }
```